# jQuery - callback not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, underscore.js

I have the following json returned from an api call. I want to check if a particular type of event is logged for certain products and if its true return an appropriate message and exit the click handler otherwise continue. I have a function called `hasEvent` to conduct this check. But when I call this function from `someOtherFunction` no message is returned even when the check is true?

```
{
  "item": {
    "Event": [
       {
         "EventType": {
             "Description": "New order"
          },
         "EventSubType": {
             "Description": "Awaiting payment"
          }
      },
      {
         "EventType": {
             "Description": "New order"
          },
          "EventSubType": {
             "Description": "Dispatched"
          }
      }
    ],
    "Errors": {
       "Result": 0,
       "Message": ""
    },
    "RecordCount": 2
  }
}


var getEvents = function (callback) {

    var orderId = $("#Id").val();

    $.getJSON('api/events?id=' + orderId)
         .done(function (data) {
               callback(data);
         }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
             return;
        });

}


var hasEvent = function (productType, callback) {

    var msg;

    getEvents(function (data) {

       _.find(data.item.Event, function (event) {

           if (event.EventType.Description == 'New order' && 
               event.EventSubType.Description == 'Dispatched' && 
               productType = 'xyz') {

               msg = 'Some message';
               return true;
           }

           if (event.EventType.Description == 'New order' && 
               event.EventSubType.Description == 'Awaiting payment' && 
               productType = 'xyz') {

               msg = 'A different message';
               return true;
           }

           // Check for Some more conditions and return appropriate message

           return false;
      });

      if (msg)
         callback(msg);

   });


}


var someOtherFunction = function () {

    $('.myselector').click(function (e) {

        var productType = $(this).attr("data-product-type");

        hasEvent(productType, function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
            // exit click event handler
            return;
        });

        // otherwise do some other stuff

        return false;
    }
}
```

What is wrong with the above code?

*** UPDATE ***

I've updated the code according to Griffins solution by adding a callback to the `hasEvent` function but now how do I exit the following click handler if an alert get displayed. The following simply continues to execute until all actions inside the click handler are complete which is not what I want - I want to exit the handler if there are events and alert displayed:

```
$('.myselector').click(function (e) {

    var productType = $(this).attr("data-product-type");

    hasEvent(productType, function(eventMsg) {
        alert(msg);
        // exit click event handler
        return;
    });

    // Do some other stuff only if no events

    return false;
}
```

Comment: `// exit click event handler` is what is wrong. also `// Do some other stuff only if no events` should be in the callback too. gogoasynchronouslogic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem in your code is that `$.getJSON` is asynchronous, meaning that when you execute it, it's starting an operation that won't be completed before the next line of code is run. When it does complete, the callback you've passed to `.done` will execute, but in that time, most of your other code will have already run.  This means that when you call `hasEvents`, you're initializing `msg` to `undefined`, then passing `getEvents` a callback that will be called when your ajax call comes back.  However, since that callback won't be immediately executed, `hasEvents` continues on and returns `msg`, which is still equal to `undefined`, which is a falsy value in Javascript.  This means that even when your ajax call comes back and the callback is executed, `hasEvent(productType)` has already evaluated to false.

One possible solution would be to give a second parameter to `hasEvent`, which is a callback. Then in your `_.find`, you could execute that callback with the message instead of returning it, like this:

```
var getEvents = function (callback) {

  var orderId = $("#Id").val();

  $.getJSON('api/events?id=' + orderId)
    .done(function (data) {
      callback(data);
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
      return;
    });

}


var hasEvent = function (productType, callback) {

  var msg = null;

  getEvents(function (data) {

    _.find(data.item.Event, function (event) {

      if (event.EventType.Description == 'New order' && 
        event.EventSubType.Description == 'Dispatched' && 
        productType = 'xyz') {

        msg = 'Some message';
        return true;
      }

      if (event.EventType.Description == 'New order' && 
        event.EventSubType.Description == 'Awaiting payment' && 
        productType = 'xyz') {

        msg = 'A different message';
        return true;
      }

      // Check for Some more conditions and return appropriate message

      return false;
    });

    callback(msg);


  });


}

var someOtherFunction = function () {

  $('.myselector').click(function (e) {

    var productType = $(this).attr("data-product-type");
    hasEvent(productType, function(eventMsg) {
      if (eventMsg) {
        console.log(eventMsg);
        alert(eventMsg);
      } else {
        console.log('there was no event!')
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Alternatively, asynchronous jquery functions return promises, so you could instead do it like this:

```
var getEvents = function (callback) {
  var orderId = $("#Id").val();
  return $.getJSON('api/events?id=' + orderId);
}


var hasEvent = function (productType) {
  return getEvents()
    .then(function (data) {

      var foundEvent = _.find(data.item.Event, function (event) {

        if (event.EventType.Description == 'New order' && 
           event.EventSubType.Description == 'Dispatched' && 
           productType = 'xyz') {
        }

        // Check for Some more conditions and return appropriate message

        return false; // if you don't return, it's undefined, which is a falsy value and has the same effect as returning false in _.find
      });

      return 'some message';

    });

}


var someOtherFunction = function () {

  $('.myselector').click(function (e) {

    var productType = $(this).attr("data-product-type");
    hasEvent(productType)
      .then(function(eventMsg) {
        console.log(eventMsg);
        alert(eventMsg);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I change the hasEvent function to return a callback with the message and exit the event handler? Can you please add some code to explain. I've tried the following - updated post but it doesnt work?

Comment: So nothing's getting logged or alerted?

Comment: I get alert but value is undefined. Also in console I get error ` call back is not a function: return callback(msg);` for the line inside my hasEvent function.

Comment: Oh oops, it looks like the callback you're passing to `hasEvent` has its parameter called `eventMsg`, but you're console.logging and alerting a variable called `msg`.  That would explain why it's alerting undefined.  Not sure about the callback error though...

Comment: I've updated the code - see original post. In the `hasEvent` function I've moved the callback outside of the `_.find` method which fixes the `call back is not a function` error and displays the alert. However if there is an error I want to exit the `$('.myselector').click(function (e) {..})` click event handler after displaying the alert without executing any other code inside the handler. How can that be achieved?

Comment: I just updated the code in my answer so that `msg` is initialized to null, then regardless of whether you find anything in your `_.find`, you can call the callback with `msg`.  Then, in the callback you define in your click handler, you can check whether `eventMsg` is truthy or falsy and either display the message if it exists or display some error message if not.